# Mock reactive return type Mono<Void>

Tags: mockito, spring-webflux, reactive

I'm using Junit 5 and mockito for some unit testing.

method call to be mocked is as follows. It returns a Mono and takes in two String arguments.

```
Mono<Void> doSomething(String id, String user);
```

I'm mocking it as follows

```
@MockBeam MyServiceClass service;
when(service.doSomething(eq(ID), eq(USER_ID)).thenReturn(Mono.empty());
```

This results a null pointers as follows

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.cabonline.schooltransport.gateway.resource.TaskResourceTest.testAssignComplaintToMe(TaskResourceTest.java:117)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:532)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:171)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:167)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:114)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:59)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:108)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:112)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:112)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Answer (score 2):

It works like follows.

```
given(service.doSomeThing(eq(ID), eq(USER_ID))).willReturn(Mono.empty());
```

Comment: @GhostCatsaysReinstateMonica not exactly. mock with `given` is what solved the problem. input arguments doesn't affect. Initial way it doesn't work with `any` or `eq`. So it is not a problem with input arguments. Something to do with now mokido do Mono<Void> stubbing.

Comment: Maybe. But I still think your question lacks a real [mcve]. It shouldnt be too difficult to create that, and your question would greatly benefit from adding it.